# Give name to child process

Tags: erlang, distributed

I have supervisor which spawns dynamic child using spawn_link. When I create new child:

```
create_my_child().
```

it return:

`{ok, <0.324.0>}`

so everything happy. I try to assign variable to child from console:

```
{ok,X} = create_my_child()
```

I get error saying:

> exception error: no match of right hand side value

and says:

> {supervisor,do_start_child_i,3

I done all difficult work, is possible to do this for child process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing all this in the console, then X is already bound to return Pid of the first `spawn_link` call, and the subsequent attempt to match `{ok, X}` with `create_my_child()` call fails with the "no match of right hand side" error.

In Erlang, variables are not mutable, so you cannot re-assign `X` after it already has a value.  In the console, you could do `f()` to the clear the shell's variables, but the easier solution is to simply bind do a different variable (ie `X2`)